# How long before push notifications are active in provisioning profile?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I've created provisioning profiles with Apple for push notifications before and was able to get them working almost immediately after registering it at `developers.apple.com`

I just created a new provisioning profile with Apple however and none of the push notifications seem to be coming through to the device. (no errors from the APNS service either). I was wondering if there is any delay before it's **"registered"** and working

Comment: There shouldn't be a delay? Have you checked if it is a production profile and if the cert supports APNS and if the profile includes the cert.

Comment: @MillieSmith we've been debugging for the past 2 days, finally blaming the provisioning profile only to just find right now that, it was a very silly mistake on the server side, where in a very specific scenario the server doesn't even make the APN call.....sigh...lol

wanna submit your answer as the an answer? I'll accept it, hopefully it'll help someone know it's not the provisioning profile. Cheers

Comment: Lol k. Thanks. Glad you fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There shouldn't be a delay before push notifications start working. Make sure the production flags match in your push notification and certificate. Also make sure the certificate supports APNS and the profile includes the certificate.